# How to get the edge coordinates？

Tags: c++, image, opencv

[Edge detection image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgG2a.jpg)

How to get the edge coordinates by opencv？

Comment: [From the docs: `cv::findNonZero()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190)

Comment: Are you asking how to get coordinate of each edge pixel individually (answered by @AlexanderReynolds) or coordinates of edge groups(contours) in your image?

Comment: yes,I want to get the coordinates of each edge pixel.Calculate the ratio of the actual distance in the graph by the coordinate value.